# Capacitance of circular parallel plate capacitors

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, dielectric

I've been trying to solve this question for a while now , but I can't seem to get to the written solution.

Question : Calculate the capacitance of a parallel capacitor having two identical conductor discs (radius R , revolution axis Oz) seperated by a dielectric of radius R, thickness d , and permittivity ϵ.

**Attempt to solve**

Using Laplace's equation:

∇^{2}V = 0

Since V only depends on z , V = Az+B

Assuming that V(0) = 0 --> B = 0

V(d) = V0 --> A = V0/d

Then We get V = (V0/d)z

Using Conductor-Dielectric Boundary Conditions:

Dn = ρs = ϵE , where ρs is the surface charge density.

Q=∫ρs . ds =  ∫ϵE.ds

E = -grad(v) = -V0/d

then we get  Q = (-ϵV0πR^2)/d

C = Q/v0 , hence C = (ϵπR^2)/d

However this differs from the solution manual which is : C = (ϵπR^2)/(d+R - √(R^2+d^2))

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If d<<R then your approximation is good

Comment: Does that mean that laplace's equation always give approximations for capacitance  and not its actual value ?

Comment: The approximation is in the geometry, not in Laplace's equation. Even the 'solution' from the manual looks like it's an approximation, valid only for certain ranges of R and d. The full solution would include the thickness of the plates, and the positions of the remote grounds. The 'parallel plate' solution of Ae/d is good where the area of the plates dominate the fringeing field round the edges. The extra terms in the 'solution' look like an approximation to the contribution of the fringing field. I suspect Bessel functions are involved, never liked those!

Comment: You 1st estimate of charge displacement for the geometry given is at fault.